# How to modify char array

Tags: visual-c++

I am reading a char array `newpath` that contains `C:\\Program Files\\test software\\app` . How to substitute the space to underscore character?

```
char newPath2[MAX_PATH];
int newCount2 = 0;

for(int i=0; i < strlen(newPath); i++)
 {
 if(newPath[i] == ' ')
    {
     newPath2[i] = '_';         
    }
    newPath2[newCount2]=0;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`newCount2` is always 0, I think you need to increment this counter too.  If not Im not sure what you are doing with this statement `newPath2[newCount2]=0;`

I think you want this:

```
for(int i=0; i < strlen(newPath); i++)
 {
 if(newPath[i] == ' ')
    {
     newPath2[i] = '_';         
    }else{
     newPath2[i]=newPath[i];
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `strlen` in `for`, is uses O(n) time - loops through the entire string each time it's called - so will make your `for` run very slowly as it gets called each step in the `for`.

Better:

```
char newPath2[MAX_PATH];
int newCount2 = 0;
const int length = strlen(newPath);

for(int i=0; i < length; i++)
 {
   if(newPath[i] == ' ')
    {
     newPath2[newCount2++] = '_';         
    } else {
     newPath2[newCount2++] = newPath[i];
    }
 }
```

This way if you need to replace space with, say, two characters (like `\<space>`), you could easily replace `newPath2[newCount2++] = '_'` with: `newPath2[newCount2++] = '\\'; newPath2[newCount2++] = ' ';`